# Connecting Android App to PHP Server Through JSON: Socket Exception

Tags: java, php, android, json, networking

I'm trying to receive a JSON object and place the contents into an ArrayList. The PHP server we set up is showing that the app is contacting the server, but nothing is sent back.
I'm not getting any fatal errors, but I'm getting a Socket Error: Permission Denied.

```html
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:454)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:517)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1108)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1454)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1413)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1707)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:247)
W/System.err:     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:737)
W/System.err:     at com.example.steve.plantpals.receiveData.receivePlantList(receiveData.java:41)
W/System.err:     at com.example.steve.plantpals.UserActivity$1.onClick(UserActivity.java:38)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:454)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:517)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1108)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1454)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1413)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1707)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:247)
W/System.err:     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:737)
W/System.err:     at com.example.steve.plantpals.receiveData.receivePlantList(receiveData.java:41)
W/System.err:     at com.example.steve.plantpals.UserActivity$1.onClick(UserActivity.java:38)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Here's where I call to receive data:

```html
public class receiveData {
    int moisture = LocalStorage.moisture;
    User user;

    ArrayList<Plant> receivedPlants = new ArrayList<Plant>();

    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.14/steve.php");

   URLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    public receiveData() throws IOException {
    }


    public ArrayList<Plant> receivePlantList() {
        // HTTP request
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        try {
            urlConnection.getContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get items from JSON object and place in a plant list
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            JsonReader jReader = new JsonReader(reader);

            jReader.beginObject();
            while (jReader.hasNext()) {
                jReader.nextName();
                int plantMoisture = jReader.nextInt();
                String plantName = jReader.nextString();
                Plant currentPlant = new Plant(plantName, plantMoisture);
                receivedPlants.add(currentPlant);
            }
            jReader.endObject();
            reader.close();
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //jReader.close();
        return receivedPlants;
    }
```

and here's my Android Manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.steve.plantpals">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyPlants"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_plants"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".AddPlant" />
        <activity android:name=".testMoistureHigh" />
        <activity android:name=".testMoistureLow" />
        <activity android:name=".testMoistureOptimal" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
        <activity android:name=".UserActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my first project requiring networking, and my first stackoverflow question, so sorry if this is unclear.

Comment: is internet permission added in Manifest?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare your permissions outside your application tag

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that before but it was giving me another error.
I'm getting that error again:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.steve.plantpals, PID: 31260
                  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: yes this is another error , because you are doing long operation in the main thread, you must use a background thread like AsyncTask, Threads, Loaders ,etc.  but the problem that you describe in the question is solve with my solution so you could mark this as accepted answer an write another question. :)